# Show button once Contact form 7 is submitted

Tags: forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I would appreciate any help. I have set a contact form up and want to show a button to download a file once the form is submitted. This is showing all the time and should be hidden until the form is filled in.

```
 <div class="visible-only-if-sent"> 
  <a href="demo.ogi.co.uk/download/1323" class="button big_large_full_width center default">Download CVM10-Lite
  </a> 
 </div>
```

But it is still showing on the page all the time. Can you please help me if I'm doing something wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can add listener on submit ..something like this:

```
  document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) 

{ if ( '123' == event.detail.contactFormId )    

  { alert( "The contact form ID is       123." ); //    do something productive } }, 

   false );
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick reply this is the code i have already added to contact form 7 <div class="visible-only-if-sent">
   <a href="https://demo.ogi.co.uk/download/1323/" class="qbutton  big_large_full_width center default">Download CVM10-Lite</a>
</div> i am not very good at code so im not sure what you mean by what you have sent me Thanks Michael

Comment: Here is a link to the page https://demo.ogi.co.uk/cmv10 as you can see the button at the bottom of the page ' DOWNLOAD CMV10-LITE ' button is showing i want to hide this until the form is submitted, the code i have sent you was working on the old site just not on the new one. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: any one help me plz >> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/403547/get-data-multi-dimensional-stdclass-object-array-with-foreach

Answer (score 0):

Using JS,
You can add an event listener that listens for when the CF7 form is submitted and add the class "visible-only-if-sent" to the element in the DOM.

Register your script in the `function.php` file in your Theme folder.

function.php

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'js-file', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/show-button.js');
```

Theme folder
Theme/JS/show-button.js

show-button.js

```
 document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) 
       { 
         var button_clicked = document.getElementsByClassName("download-file"); 
         button_clicked.classList.add("visible-only-if-sent");
       }, 

 false );
```

Template file

```
<div class="download-file"> 
  <a href="demo.ogi.co.uk/download/1323" class="button big_large_full_width center default">Download CVM10-Lite
  </a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code
This code work after completly submitting form 'wpcf7mailsent'

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) 

       { 
<!-- write whatever you want -->
       let btn = document.getElementById('show_pdf');
        btn.style.display = "block";   
       }, 
 false );
</script>
```